# Paste exact file path in R and format back slash to forward slash? (without getting hex digit issue

Tags: r, path, hex, rstudio, filereader

I want to be able to paste the file path exactly as it is and then later format it. Reason is I have a script that takes in a directory and processses all the files in it. The user just has to input a few lines of info in the beginning (including the source folder path), and then just sit and wait for the rest to load. I want the user to have little manual intervention (ie, don't want to have to fix the slashes myself)

For some reason, I can't seem to get it to work. It still gives the "\U used without hex digits in character string starting..." issue

Example:

1. I paste file path as such:

> source_folder <- ('C:\Users\myname\Turtles\iLike')

2. Script should then alter the source_folder variable to become

> 'C:/Users/myname/Turtles/iLike'

Then the rest of the script should flow smoothly.

I think I'll have to change how I store the path right after pasting, but not sure the easiest way for the end user. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not use `file.path` to creeate the path

Comment: *Users* should not edit source files, full stop. The conventional way to do this is to provide the paths as command line options when invoking the script (via the command line). Bonus: that way you don't need to modify the path strings at all. — Better yet, if the input is a directory, it is often conventional for the script to assume that the current working directory is what the user wants, i.e. use `getwd()` instead of a user-supplied path. The user then simply has to launch the script in the desired folder.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question, but if users are going to copy/paste the directory to your application/script, you can use `readClipboard()` and just let them know that they need to copy the file path, before proceeding.

Answer (score 1):

R supports the following string format so one can simply paste a path.  See `?Quotes` for additional variations that are accepted.

```
source_folder <- r'(C:\Users\myname\Turtles\iLike)'
```

Another possiblity is to use this, on Windows only, which will present a GUI dialog that the user can use to set the directory.

```
source_folder <- choose.dir()
```

An OS independent alternative to `choose.dir` is the following.  Note that tcltk comes with R in all standard R distributions.

```
tcltk::tk_choose.dir()
```

There are also a number of packages which include functions for this purpose including rChoiceDialogs, gWidgets and others.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfect. so the " r' " in front overrides it essentially?



One other thing I am wondering.....is it possible to get a user prompt with two or three textboxes (for different inputs) and to store that into 2-3 variables?

Example: I want to load a file to a specific database/schema/table in SQL and am debating adding a Prompt to ask the user to type it in, but would rather not have 3 separate prompts that pop up one after the other

Comment: To create a custom GUI the main alternatives are tcltk (which comes with R on all standard distributions) or shiny (a package on CRAN).  The rpanel and gWidgets packages are higher level packages for tcltk.  There are numerous packages that use or work with tcltk or shiny.  See the shiny CRAN page for a list of the latter  https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=shiny